Go mod download got stuck while running on docker file
I am trying to create a docker image with the following Dockerfile.
    FROM golang:latest
    WORKDIR /app
    ENV GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org
    ENV GOPROXY=direct
    COPY go.mod .
    COPY go.sum .
    RUN go mod download 
    COPY . .
    RUN go build -o ./out/dist .
    

I was able to build the go executable in my local machine. but when i run the "docker build -t app . " command. It got stuck while running the "go mod download" command.

I waited for more than an hour. Every time it got stuck while downloading filippo.io/edwards255919 file.
I have tried setting GOPROXY and changing the go version. unfortunately it doesn't work.
I dont have any proxy in my computer.
How to build the docker container without getting stuck.

I suggest that,

Try to add ,direct suffix to your GOPROXY environment variable first and build.

Then, modify the GOPROXY to https://goproxy.io,direct and build.


If none of they works, try go mod vendor to download all dependencies to your project root and copy them into your builder image. Add flag -mod=vendor for go build command in Dockerfile to enforce loading dependencies from existing vendor.
